# How do I use strings in functions for R ? (file,rt error)

Tags: r, string, function

I am trying to load data into a function to use for analysis later on and there seems to be issues inserting a string (i.e. a filename) into my function. Here is what I am working with.

```
hist_sep<- function(dex_file,etoh_file,sep_parameter) {
dex<-read.csv("dex_file")$sep_parameter
etoh<-read.csv("etoh_file")$sep_parameter
}
```

The code below outputs this error

```
hist_sep(RT_3h_Amp_A.csv , RT_3h_Amp_EtOH_A.csv , FL1.A)

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
```

However, if I input the filenames myself (as below) then everything works great. So everything is in the correct directory.

```
dex<-read.csv("RT_3h_Amp_A.csv")$FL1.A
etoh<-read.csv("RT_3h_Amp_EtOH_A.csv")$FL1.A
```

Any ideas how I could get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the filenames in your function (e.g., should be `dex<-read.csv(dex_file)$sep_parameter`, not `dex<-read.csv("dex_file")$sep_parameter`). Otherwise, it's trying to download a file CALLED "dex_file".

Comment: and add quotes inside `hist_sep(RT_3h_Amp_A.csv , RT_3h_Amp_EtOH_A.csv , FL1.A)`

Comment: Works. Thank you.